# Beaglebone Black or raspberry PI?

Tags: wifi, iot, beagleboneblack, raspberry-pi3, texas-instruments

I had a question about the Beaglebone Black. why texas instruments  suggest using Beaglebone Black instead of Raspberry PI 3 which has Bluetooth and Wi-Fi chip inside and it is cheaper and more powerful. Is there any special reason ?

Comment: Beaglebone black has TI processor and Raspberry Pi has Broadcomm processor. Also BBB has more IO pins and many communication interfaces are readily available without the use of a shield. It's also less powerful than Raspi.

Comment: If you buy hardware by glossy feature lists, the RPi wins hands down. If you *actually* do custom embedded Linux projects, then there is no clear cut answer and it will depend on project requirements. If you need a fully open source boot process, it's BBB. If you need an ADC with 8 channels, then the BBB has that out of the box. If you need WiFi, then it's USB on the BBB vs the SDIO connected chip on the RPi3. In the end it will very much depend on actual project requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the extra GPIO pins. But also the embedded PRUs. The beaglebone black has 2 extra RISC processors onboard that are great for PID loops if you want to get experience with TI's assembly programming.

Answer (score 1):

All the features mentioned in the above answers are true, but most important point of using BBB is hardware flexibility and robustness. BBB has external emmc, and has a SD card slot so you can easily use the slot for other purposes, also the OS gets stored on the emmc which has high speed 8-bit parallel interface with the processor. Rpi has it OS on sd card, which if removed is of no use.

So i consider BBB as a miniature full blown linux system best for use in IoT applications.